# dll needed at runtime if lib included?

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I want to create a .dll (in C++) that uses RAPI. For this I create the visual studio project and then I set the additional include directories to the place where I have "rapi2.h" needed, and also the additional link directories to the place where rapi.lib is located.

Then I write another application using my created .dll file. This method works fine, but at runtime I need rapi.dll to be existent on the computer running my application.

Is there any way to add a .dll into another .dll s that the first is not needed at runtime?

Maybe this is a beginner question, but why do I need the dll at runtime but at compilation is enough only the .lib, and .h associated?

Comment: A `lib` doesn't imply a static link -- it can be used for both static and dynamic links. It's simply for resolving references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between [dynamic linking and static linking](http://simplesamples.info/Beginners/StaticVersusDynamic.php).  In your case, the lib is an import library only and does not contain actual executable code.  That is dynamically linked at runtime.

Comment: I read the article. things are more clear now. And how can I do the statically linking using visual studio preferably?

Comment: You can only statically link if a static library is provided.  For example if there were a rapi.lib import library and a rapi.lib static library (that contained the code found in rapi.dll).  Typically this is not done on Windows.  If the code you are calling is in rapi.dll only then you have no choice but to utilize this .dll unless you were to rewrite all of it's exported functions yourself.

Comment: All clear now, even difference between import library and static library. Thanks a lot!